# JavaScript keypress event to limit the maximum value

Tags: javascript

In my page textbox value need to set maximum allowed value so I using javscript to control it. In below code to control the maximum limit value it works fine (i.e) if I 235 then 5 is not allowed. Then I 23 to I select 2 to type 4 that situation below code is not working.

**Javascript**

```
function hourCount(id, e) {
   var keynum;
   if (window.event) { //IE
       keynum = e.keyCode;
   } else if (e.which) {
       keynum = e.which;
   } if (id !== undefined) {
       console.info("hour text box Value : " + id.value);
       console.info("Charcter key press value : " + String.fromCharCode(keynum));

       var currentValue = id.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);

       console.info("Combine value :" + currentValue);
       if (currentValue > 23) {
           console.info("Then Result is :" + currentValue);
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
   } else {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
}
```

**xhtml page**

```
<h:inputText value="#{user.limitValue}" onkeyPress="hour(this,event)"/>
```

My doubt is if I press 235 situation to 5 not allowed then select 2 to type 4 allowed.If any problem  **currentValue = id.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);** in this statement then how to solve it?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't intercept keystrokes. It's a poor user experience. Use the `max` attribute instead.

Comment: First off, if you must intercept keystrokes, use keyup for a more appropriate result.  Second, you're dealing in strings, so '2' + '2' = '22'.  If you want numbers you have to parseInt() or parseFloat(), and check for NaN values.